# FFMPEG Add 2 watermarks (txt + png) to a video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to add 2 watermarks to a video, one should be a .png file and the second some moving/scrolling text.

Png  = fixed at right bottom

Text = Moving/scrolling from the top right to the top left. Starting at 50% of total video length (appear at 1:00 if total length is 2:00) and disappearing in 20 seconds.

I already use a command to encode the video and add a logo at the right bottom but having trouble adding scrolling text at the same time.

```
-i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h-4" -keyint_min 20 -vcodec libx264 -c:a copy -b:v 1500k -movflags +faststart
```

Comment: Hey @razz, Could you tell me , where have you placd your logo.png file in android studio ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate overlay and drawtext filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h),drawtext=text=string1:y=line_h-10:x='if(gte(t,30),w-(t-30)*w/20,w)'" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

In this example, the video lasts 60s, so I set 30s into the if block. If you need to automate the video length, I recommend you a bash script (use ffprobe to get the duration). You can also customize the font (color, size...) adding colons between properties. More info:

- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext
- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay

Comment: Can be simplified with `...overlay_h),drawtext` as overlay is outputting only 1 stream and drawtext accepts only 1 stream. You can use format filter instead of legacy `-pix_fmt` to keep all filtering in one filtergraph.

Comment: @m8factorial
This basically does what i requested, however i should have been more clear about "starting at 50%" which should be "starting at 50% of total video length"

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h-4)[out];[out]drawtext=fontsize=20:font=tahoma:alpha=0.5:fontcolor=white:borderw=0.8:bordercolor=black:text=This is some text to use :y=line_h-4:x=w-(t-30)*w/30" -keyint_min 20 -vcodec libx264 -c:a copy -b:v 1500k -movflags +faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4 `

I adjusted the code a bit. I could not figure out to show text at 50% video length so i set it to start at 30 sec and last 30 sec. I also included some other values for the output

Comment: @llogan @m8factorial
I have to ask one more thing.
The text and font size i'm using looks acceptable on 1280px but on lower or higher px not, so i need something related to scaling. This also applies on the logo.

Logo = 400x93 px so i figured that this should scale the logo `scale2ref=400*iw/1280:93*iw/1280` but what about drawtext?

Comment: @razz You'll have to choose an appropriate `fontsize`.

Comment: I've improve my answer, so I think it's fine now. Thanks!